# Currency data type of VB 6 to C++

Tags: vb6

I am calling a C++ function from VB6.
In which I need to pass variable of Currency datatype.
But in C++ we do not have such datatype.
what should I use in C++ function to make the compatibility with currency datatype?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best bet is to pass it as a [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) and manually handle the VARIANT in the C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

The VB6s **currency** type is roughly the same as the **`CY`** type from C++ (assuming a Microsoft compiler)

Internally it is an **8-byte integer** which is scaled by a **factor of 10,000**, giving you 4 digits after the decimal separator.

Depending on the compiler you can directly use the `CY` type or pass a `VARIANT` and use `myVariant.cyVal` (which is of the `CY` type).

If you don't have the `VARIANT` and `CY` type available (they are not part of the C++ standard) your C++ function has to accept a 64-bit integer and you have to divide the value by 10,000 to get the correct value. (Either use `__int64` or `long long`, again depending on the compiler)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Visual C++ has a native 64-bit integer type [__int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z(VS.80).aspx) (also known as [CY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221223.aspx)), which is roughly equivalent to VB6 Currency? Although in your C++ code you will "see" the value as 10,000 times larger than the value you "see" in VB6. Either divide by 10,000 in the C++ to get the correct value, or work with the scaled value to keep the precision.

For other C++ compilers Bruce McKinney's bible *Hardcore Visual Basic* [recommends](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/largeintegerscurrency.htm) something like this, so does [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221223.aspx):

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG  HighPart;
    };
    LONGLONG QuadPart;    // In Visual C++, a typedef to __int64
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

See [here](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/largeintegerscurrency.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `currency` type and multiply it by 100, then pass it to C++ as a `long` integer. When you needs results back, do the reverse.

There will be no loss of precision, and the code is very simple.

Comment: Although you will get an overflow if the answer exceeds the possible range of a long.

Comment: True, if the amount exceeds $20 000 000 :)  If the amounts are large, then an `__int64` would be more appropriate.